# Regex for space slash space

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to match any instance of [space][slash][space].

ie.

```
" / "
```

in a regex pattern.

I can't find the answer anywhere. What have I missed?

```
function madeby_remove_slash($text) {
    preg_replace('/ \/ /', ' ', $text);
    return $text;
}
echo madeby_remove_slash('This is the / text');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't assign the return value of the preg_replace to the `$text` variable in your function.

```
function madeby_remove_slash($text) {
    return preg_replace('/ \/ /', ' ', $text); // return what the preg_replace returns
}
```

or if you want to replace a literal string you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) too.

```
str_replace(' / ', ' ', $text); // this works too
```

Comment: Piggy-backing on this, instead of `return $text`, why not just `return preg_replace.....`?

Answer (score 0):

\s/\s

And use this [tool](http://rubular.com/), it's cool!

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the enclosing forward-slashes from your regex.  AFAIK they're not necessary in PHP, and it may well be thinking that you're asking it to match those as well.